# Solving $y'=f(x, y)$ where $\forall k>0. f(kx, ky) = f(x, y) \ne f(-x, -y) = f(-kx, -ky)$ (Tom Apostol Calculus vol. $1$, ex. $8.26.6$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Tom Apostol wrote that a homogeneous first-order equation is of a form

$y' = f(x, y)$, where $\forall x,y \in R. \forall t \ne 0. f(x, y) = f(tx, ty)$.

Now, his excercise $8.26.6$ is:

$xy' = y - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Can be transformer into something which looks like a first-order homogeneous equation:

$y' = \frac{y - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x}$

However, I'm not sure why it can be seen as such, because for negative $t$, it does not hold that $f(x, y) = f(-x, -y)$. Namely:

$f(x, y) = \frac{y - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x}$

$f(-x, -y) = \frac{-y - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{-x} = \frac{y + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x} \ne f(x, y)$

However, if we proceed and solve it as a homogeneous solution (e.g. by introducing $v = \frac{y}{x}$), we can solve it.

Why is that justified, even though $f(x, y) = f(tx, ty)$ only for $t>0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objection is justified. Actually, at the beginning of $8.25$, do you see his example:
$$y' = \log(x)-\log(y)$$
As it is written, this also isn't homogeneous. The logarithm won't make sense as it has been written. Now, for your case, you actually can't quite solve it using homogeneity. This is because:
$$xy' = y - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = y- |x| \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{x} \right)^2}$$

Division by $x$ throughout won't yield what you want. You'll have to consider two intervals in this case; $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expand on why it's valid to consider the two intervals separately, as well as how you would approach the negative interval? For example, if x>0, it is easy to apply $f(1, y/x)$ as usual. However, if x<0, I'm not sure if I should use f(-1, y/x). If yes, then it would be f(-x, y), which is quite similar to the positive case (because $-x$ is positive). If no, then it would be f(1, y/x), which is again the same as the positive case, so I'm not sure why it would be valid to do that.